# Avoid double fire in cascading observable chain

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I seem to keep running into situations like the following:

```
private categoryFilter: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
private subcategoryFilter: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

constructor() {
  this.categoryFilter.subscribe(newCategory => {
    let newSubcategory = this.getDefaultSubcategoryForCategory(newCategory);
    this.subcategoryFilter.next(newSubcategory);
  });
  this.categoryFilter.combineLatest(this.subcategoryFilter, (cat, sub) => {
    return this.createSearchCriteria(cat, sub);
  }).subscribe(searchCriteria => {
    this.doExpensiveSearch(searchCriteria);
  });
}
```

Everything works great when the user changes the subcatgory (a new search is issued).  However, if the user changes the category then the combined observable fires twice (once for the category change and once for the subcategory change).

There are some (I think clumsy) approaches I've taken such as:

1. Change to behavior subjects, only subscribe to the subcategory filter, and use the category filter's synchronous value.  I don't like this approach because there isn't always an obvious parent/child relationship like my example.
2. Same as 1 but use `withLatestFrom` instead of behavior subjects.  This also doesn't work if there isn't a clear parent/child relationship.
3. Debounce the `combineLatest` with a small time window.  This works but feels clumsy.

Is there a better way of avoiding a double fire in this situation?